# How to properly reference a global variable in nested functions in Python

Tags: python, global-scope

Let's say I have the following simple situation:

```
import pandas as pd

def multiply(row):
    global results
    results.append(row[0] * row[1])

def main():
    results = []
    df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}])
    df.apply(multiply, axis=1)
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This results in the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-58ca95c5b364>", line 1, in <module>
    main()

  File "<ipython-input-1-9bb1bda9e141>", line 11, in main
    df.apply(multiply, axis=1)

  File "C:\Users\bbritten\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4262, in apply
    ignore_failures=ignore_failures)

  File "C:\Users\bbritten\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4358, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)

  File "<ipython-input-1-9bb1bda9e141>", line 5, in multiply
    results.append(row[0] * row[1])

NameError: ("name 'results' is not defined", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I know that I can move `results = []` to the `if` statement to get this example to work, but is there a way to keep the structure I have now and make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must declare results outside the functions like:

```
import pandas as pd

results = []

def multiply(row):
    # the rest of your code...
```

#### UPDATE

Also note that `list` in python is mutable, hence you don't need to specify it with global in the beginning of the functions. Example

```
def multiply(row):
    # global results -> This is not necessary!
    results.append(row[0] * row[1])
```

Comment: So the variables must be truly global in nature, and cannot be defined in a local scope, such as what I was doing. Is that what you're saying? I'm likely not going to use the right terminology here, but is there a way to access the environment of a calling function? So, for example, can I specify that `multiply` should use the environment of `main` for variables?

Comment: This still won't fix your problem.

Comment: Yes. If you want a global variable you must declare it outside of the scope of any function, the `global` keyword just says that variable you're manipulating is actually the global one rather than a new one created locally inside this function. If you wan't to make a variable "environment specific" you should use **classes** then.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Technically this answer _does_ fix the problem. It fixes the TraceBack the OP posted in their question. However as you noted in your (now deleted) answer, if the OP wants to use `multiply` with `df.apply()`, they need to return an actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You must move results outside of the function. I don't think there is any other way without moving the variable out.

One way is to pass results as a parameter to multiply method.